# Azure Web App Service returns 403 HostNames Disabled

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

I created an Azure web app service using Bicep, and after deploying the code when calling the API it returns:

> 403 HostNames Disabled

If I access the host through the UI it shows:

> Error 403 - This web app is stopped

I have tried following the recommendations and it doesn't seem to be an issue of restarting, quotas, or a code issue. I tried with Kudu/CMD to start my site with `dotnet MyApp.dll` and it starts correctly.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing my own Bicep code, I realized I had set the property `hostNamesDisabled` to true, causing the application to return the status code above.